# Why do we use "executed" in referral to carrying something out?

Tags: meaning, expressions

The wording, given the standard meaning of "executed" - which is often in a negative light, as per the term - seems strange.
Has the term been adopted into it's current (stated) usage or has it always been defined to where you can use it like that?

Comment: The meaning ‘carry out’ _is_ the ‘standard meaning’ of _execute_. So is the meaning ‘kill as punishment’. There is nothing strange about a word having to ‘standard meanings’, even if they are very different. The word originally means ‘carry out’ or ‘follow through’, and was simply used idiomatically to carry out a specific thing: a death sentence (from the 14th century, according to Etymonline).

Comment: @Janus: Possibly the capital punishment meaning of execution started out as a euphemism, although finding evidence for this seven centuries later is probably impossible.

Answer (score 1):

*Execute* derives from medieval Latin *executare*, meaning "to carry out," through Anglo-French *executer*. The association of "execution" with capital punishment arose in the mid-14th century via "[don execution of deth](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=execution&allowed_in_frame=0)," a Middle English legal phrase that was used to instruct an authority to carry out a death sentence. The standardized phrase "execution of death" seems to have survived into the [17th century](http://books.google.com/books?id=uolDAAAAIAAJ&pg=RA1-PA83&dq=%22execution+of+death%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fgimU8aAC8_-oQSv54DAAQ&ved=0CFIQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22execution%20of%20death%22&f=false) in some form, while standalone "execute" in the capital punishment sense was well established by [the beginning of the 19th century](http://books.google.com/books?id=wzM0AQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PR50&dq=%22execute%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aQmmU5ajNdHboASzsYGICQ&ved=0CE8Q6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22execute%22&f=false), and probably well before that.